# Check current time against time in database and header to expire page if one hour passed

Tags: php, mysqli

this is a "reset password form" and I need to expire this page whiten one hour so if the user clicked the link to reach the page again after one hour he will be direct to expire page so I made this table in my database which content this column "check_time" the db column type is "`datetime`" now 
I need to Check current time against the time in database and header the users to expire page if one hour passed

```
$email = $token = $check_time = "";

$crossToken = $db->prepare("SELECT email, token, check_time FROM pw_reset_company WHERE token=? LIMIT 1");
$crossToken->bind_param('s', $c);
if ($crossToken->execute()) {
    $crossToken->bind_result($email, $token, $check_time);
    $crossToken->store_result();
    $rowCount = $crossToken->num_rows;
    if ($crossToken->fetch()) {
        $contactEmail = $email;
        $timeToExpire = $check_time;
    }
    if ($rowCount > 0) {
        date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
        $checkTime = date("H:i:s", time());
        if($timeToExpire>$checkTime){
            header("Location:?pid=expired");
        }
        ?>
        <form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
            <label for="password">Enter New Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
            <label for="confirm">Enter New Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="confirm" id="confirm">
            <input type="submit" name="subNewPass" id="subNewPass" value="Reset Password">
        </form>
    <?php
    } elseif ($_GET['c'] && !(empty($_GET['c']))) {
        header("Location:?pid=expired");
    }
}
```

**Edit**
Sorry if I didn't describe my problem correctly

here is the part of code that has the problem

```
if ($rowCount > 0) {
        $newTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $checkTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 hour', strtotime($newTime)));
        if ($dbTime < $checkTime) {
            header("Location:?pid=companyManagePasswords&mp=expire");
        }
```

I edit this part yesterday here is what happen, every time I try to access the reset password page it redirect to the expire page it should do that after one hour.

please help me to edit this part to make the reset page expire after 1 hour.

someone suggest to make it something like this

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM `DB` WHERE `ID` = 1 AND `TIME` < '" . $checkTime ."'";
```

still not what I want.
any ideas

Comment: And what is wrong here?

Comment: @u_mulder I can't get this working properly it always direct to expire page even if I just requested the reset ... it should header to the expire page after one hour

Comment: even I try this `$checkTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+1 hour'));` but it didn't help me solving the issue